# Python and OpenCV - Dominant Line in Hough Line transform

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, houghlinesp

For my program, using OpenCV and Python, I'm trying to detect road lanes. In order to accomplish this, I used Hough Line Transform to detect lines. However, it finds many lines right next to each other and I'm trying to find a way to make an average line that's in between all of those other lines. Tips?

Here's my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('CVfootage.mov')

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = frame[200:720, 0:1280]    
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)
        edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)

        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=80)

        a,b,c = lines.shape
        for i in range(a):
            cv2.line(blur, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
        cv2.imshow('hough', blur)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hard to image what you are referring as "many lines right next to each" without visualizing an example. You mean that the thresholding isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to adjust the parameter of the houghlinesP function

if you want less lines next to each other : increase 'rho'

if you want less lines in general  : increase threshold